# Track changes within DOM element with MutationObserver Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, mutation-observers

I found a website that pushes darts scores. Each time a new score is published, I would like to be notified.

```
import time
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

URL = 'https://live.dartsdata.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/hjam/downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get(URL)

time.sleep(1)
matches = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*[@class='sr-match__wrapper srt-base-1 sr-ml-list__match']")
matches[0].click()
```

I want to retrieve the seconds until the match starts (there are no live matches atm, but idea is the same). I see that this data point is located in

```
seconds = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*[@class='sr-lmt-0-ms-countdown__time srt-primary-7 srm-large']")[-1]
```

Now I want to use a `MutationObserver` to track the changes of this element. Each time the element changes, I want it to be printed. Using the example of [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) I write the following

```
driver.execute_script("""
const targetNode = document.querySelector('#content1 > div.sr-lmt-plus__comp.srm-double.srm-isLmt > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.sr-lmt-wrap > div > div.sr-lmt-22-state > div.sr-bb.sr-lmt-matchstatus.sr-ltr.sr-lmt-matchstatus--small > div > div > div.sr-lmt-matchstatus__slider.sr-slider-flex__slider > div > div > div.sr-lmt-setsports-ms-matchstatus__row.sr-lmt-setsports-ms-matchstatus__countdown-wrapper > div > div.sr-lmt-0-ms-countdown__row > div:nth-child(4)');
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
            console.log('Time is ticking');
        }
    };
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
""")
```

This yields no error, but nothing happens. It should print continuously *'time is ticking'* in the Console right?

[image]

What am I doing wrong? And is there also a possibility that the output is printed in my python-script?

Comment: The array syntax is not valid on an array like structure. `-1` is not valid.

Comment: tnx the error is gone now, but there is no output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

querySelectorAll is not live. It's returns representations of what the dom was and you're monitoring that snapshot. You need to use getElementsByClassName to hook onto a live element.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If I change the script as follows:
`var targetNode = document.getElementsByClassName('sr-lmt-0-ms-countdown__time srt-primary-7 srm-large')[3];` , I still see no log output in the Console

Comment: cos you're missing 'characterData: true' in the config

Comment: @HJA24 After `characterData: true` is the mutationobserver working at your end? I mean throwing _`Time is ticking`_ to the console?

Comment: yes it works after adding that!